# Getting full access to DynamoDB from my ios app using AWS Cognito Developer Identities

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have implemented a AWS Lambda function and used the gateway to return the fulling data:

```
var param =
{
    IdentityPoolId: "actualIdentityPoolId",
    Logins: {} // To have provider name in a variable
};
param.Logins["com.testing.userLogin"] = userId;

cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(param,
function(err, data)
{
    if (err) return fn(err); // an error occurred
    else fn(null, data.IdentityId, data.Token); // successful response
});
```

So the identityId and token get sent back to the ios device. In my device I try to connect to an AWS DynamoDB table but access is denied.  How do I use the identityId and token to gain access to the tables?

I have set up roles in IAM for Unauth which denies Dydnamo and Auth which gives access to the tables through its policies.

I am trying to implement authentication using: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html

I see there are two flows which are Basic and Enhanced. The documentation says most users will use the enhanced flow and that implements GetCredentialForIdentity.

How is that implemented in my ios code so that I can switch my role from unauth to auth and can access to dynamodb? How long will this access last? I would like to do this all in my ios code instead of using lambda or something else like that.

Answer (score 3):

If your user is unauthenticated, then logs in you need to clear your credentials, and your 'logins' method should now return a properly updated logins map.

Here is the documentation to help you:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

Comment: I used that link but still no dice and dynamodb still remains unauthenticated.

Answer (score 2):

Double check your DynanoDB Roles for authenticated access your DynamoDB resource.  An example role for this are on the [following page of the developer guide you referenced](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html).  The page is called "**IAM Roles**" and the last section is the important one: "**Fine-Grained Access to Amazon DynamoDB**".

Stick with your plan to use the Enhanced Authflow.  It is recommended and makes less calls to authenticate (your users will appreciate this).  Just make sure you mobile clients call `GetCredentialsForIdentity` from iOS.

[image]

From the Enhanced Authflow documentation further down your page:

> The GetCredentialsForIdentity API can be called after you establish an identity ID. This API is functionally equivalent to calling GetOpenIdToken followed by **AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity**.

The AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity is the important piece that allows your user to assume the Role that gets access to the DynamoDB resource.  Cognito will take care of the rest as long as you set up the Roles correctly within the Cognito console:

> In order for Amazon Cognito to call AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity on your behalf, your identity pool must have IAM roles associated with it. You can do this via the Amazon Cognito Console or manually via the SetIdentityPoolRoles operation (see the API reference)

Comment: I set up everything using lambda and get the identityId and token back. It's figuring out what and how to set up the objective-c part that is confusing me and call GetCredentialsForIdentity. I have congnito and all the roles setup up correctly for auth users and full access on the authenticated role.

Comment: refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html .  The last 2 steps detail all you need to do for IOS - Retrieving an Amazon Cognito ID and AWS Credentials.  You don't actually call GetCredentialsForIdentity , but it is called for you when you use the AWS SDK and DynamoDB client code.  For example in the http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

Comment: Why did I call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity if the identityId and token are never added to the code you mentioned above? I want to switch from my unauth role to my auth role too.